# Oracle to_date return incorrect result

Tags: oracle11g, to-date

I have a table 4 columns - Code, Status, EffectiveDate (EFF_DT), EndDate (END_DT). All the columns are Varchar2 type. EFF_DT and END_DT has ISO format date (YYYY-MM-DD) with NULL values for few rows. Need to get the rows which has END_DT greater than today's date.
While executing the below query, it returns all the Not NULL rows for END_DT. Do not compare the END_DT at all.

```
select code, status, EFF_DT, END_DT 
from (
  select CODE, EFF_DT, Status,to_date("END_DT" ,'YYYY-MM-DD' ) as END_DT 
  from xxx.ZZZ 
) TAB 
where to_date(TAB.END_DT ,'DD-MM-YY' ) >  to_date(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Date), 'DD-MM-YY') 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

But the below query compares the END_DT and returns the result properly -

```
SELECT "TAB"."CODE"  ,  "TAB"."STATUS" AS "STATUS" , "TAB"."EFF_DT"  , "TAB"."END_DT"  
FROM xxx.ZZZ  "TAB"  
WHERE (  (to_date("TAB"."END_DT",'YYYY-MM-DD') >  to_date(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Date), 'YY-MM-DD'))    ) 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

What is going wrong with the 1st query?
I see difference in return value of END_DT.
For the 1st query, the data is coming like -

[image]

while as for the 2nd query, the data is coming like

[image]

Comment: replace `to_date(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Date), 'DD-MM-YY')` with `current_date`. **Never** call `to_date()` with a parameter that is already a date or timestamp values. That only converts the date to a varchar just to convert that back to a date which it was to begin with

Comment: Why on earth are you storing `DATE` values in a `VARCHAR` column? That is a horrible idea.

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name ! It worked!